# what does it mean that Mahalanobis distance matches on all interactions

Tags: multivariate-analysis, distance, matching

Some papers write that matching based on the Mahalanobis distance between subjects can be difficult because it attempts to match on all possible interactions between covariates. What does this mean and what is the geometric interpretation?